# Using Socket.io Namespace in MEAN.js 4.2

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io, mean-stack, meanjs

I'm building an application with MEAN.js 4.2, and am trying to use Socket.io to have the server emit certain messages that the UI will respond to in real time. For example, when the server posts a Note to the user's Notebook, the Notebook will refresh its contents in the UI.

I want to use namespacing to make sure that I am emitting the event only to the affected user, and that the user is only listening to relevant events.

On the server, I have:

```
var namespace = '/player-' + user._id;  // whereas user._id is the user's unique id
var nsp = io.of(namespace);

nsp.emit('note.posted', note);  // whereas note contains info about the posted note
```

Then, on the client-side controller:

```
angular.module('myapp')
  .controller('NotebookController', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$http', 'Authentication', 'Notebook', 'Socket', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $http, Authentication, Notebook, Socket) {

...

  var nsp = '/player-' + Authentication.user._id;  // This gives me the same namespace as used on the server.  I just don't know what to do with it.

  if (!Socket.socket) {
    Socket.connect();
  }

  Socket.on('note.posted', function (data) {
    $scope.find();  // this just refreshes the list of notes in the UI
  });

  $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    Socket.removeListener('note.posted');
  });

...
```

So, the client-side namespace is still '/', since I haven't connected to the other namespace anywhere.  Indeed, I verified that Socket.socket.nsp = '/' when the listener is set.

If I emit the event in the default namespace, everything works perfectly ... except that the event goes out to every client connected to the default namespace.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `Socket.connect(nsp)`?

Comment: @mef: socket.io does not support dynamic namespaces, so you have to create the namespace on the server before you connect with the client.

Comment: @bolav he can still create the namespaces on the server when the user authenticates, as long as that happens before the socket.io connection...

Comment: @mef: Exactly what I said, anyways this seems like abuse, when his usecase could just as well use rooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

namespaces in Socket.IO is not meant to be used dynamic, like you are doing here. It looks like it is more meant to have different applications running on one server.

What you should use is rooms.

**Server code**:

```
var room = 'player-' + user._id;  // whereas user._id is the user's unique id
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.join(room);
});

// This is to send the note
io.to(room).emit('note.posted', note);  // whereas note contains info about the posted note
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was just reading a comparison of namespaces and rooms, and was starting to come to this conclusion.  I'll try this out ...

Comment: Brilliant!  Spot on!  This is more secure too, since I can regulate access on the server.